# Let, $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $A$ can contain at most one point $p$ such that $A$ is isometric to $A \setminus \{p\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, contest-math, isometry

A challenge problem from [Sally's Fundamentals of Mathematical Analysis.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821891413)

> Problem reads: Suppose $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $A$ can contain at most one point $p$ such that $A$ is isometric to $A \setminus \{p\}$ with the usual metric.

I'm really not sure where to begin. I've found a fairly trivial example of a set for which this is true: let $A$, for example, be $\{(n,0) : n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb{Z}^+\}$. Then we may remove the point $(0,0)$ and construct the isometry $f(n,0) = (n+1, 0)$. This is clearly an isometry because $d((n,0),(m,0)) = d((n+1,0),(m+1,0))$, in other words, we are just shifting to the right. But now suppose we remove some $(p,0) \neq (0,0)$. Then we must have $d((m,0), (m+1,0)) = 1$ for all points $(m,0), (m+1,0)$, but since $(p,0)$ was removed we will always have a "jump" point where the distance between two successive points is $2$.

But I'm not sure where to proceed. Isometries are equivalence relations, so maybe we can show that if $A \setminus \{p\}$ is isometric to $A \setminus \{q\}$, then $p = q$?

I will say that given how often Sally's errant in his book and that some of the other challenge problems are open problems, this might not have a reasonable solution (if it's even true).

Any ideas?

> To avoid any confusion, the problem isn't asking a proof for the set not being isometric to itself minus two points at the same time. It's asking for a proof that there is at most one unique point that you can remove from the set and then create an isometry. This was something I misinterpreted for a while.

Edit: This is still stumping me. I'm beginning to wonder whether it's even true at all. Well, I've put a bounty on it, which hopefully serves as bit more incentive to try this problem out!

Comment: Good example, well thought through.  This looks like a toughie.

Comment: Quick observations: the point $p$ to be removed must necessarily be an isolated point.  $A$ must have infinitely many isolated points

Comment: @Chris this is not clear

Comment: @DavidBowman Your example is bit confusing to me. If you remove the first two points, i.e. $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ from A, then the map $(n,0) \mapsto (n+2,0)$ is still an isometry from $A$ onto $A\setminus \{(0,0),(1,0)\}$. But this contradicts the main statement. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Sayantan I believe what is meant by the statement is ``if $p,q\in A$ are points such that $A\setminus\{p\}$ and $A\setminus\{q\}$ are both isometric to $A$ (with the usual metric), then $p = q$."

Comment: @Sayantan yes, we are only removing one point. But we're showing that for each set, we can remove (if we can remove any at all, presumably some sets wouldn't allow removal) a unique point, and that point only.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: A need not have any isolated points: let $A=\{\langle 1,n\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\}$, where the ordered pairs are polar coordinates. An anticlockwise rotation about the origin through $1$ radian is an isometry of $A$ to $A\setminus\{\langle 1,0\rangle\}$, and $A$ is dense in $S^1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I should have thought of that (Banach Tarski and all).  With a bit more thought, I realize the flaw in the proof that I had had in mind.  There is no contradiction in having a sequence in $A \setminus \langle 1,0 \rangle$ that converges to $\langle 1,0 \rangle$ in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: The requirement to use the usual metric does mean that every isometry is the restriction to $A$ of a rigid motion of the plane (including reflections); I don’t immediately see how to use this, but it does seem worth noting.

Comment: Well, an isometry $\Phi$ over $\Bbb R^2$ with $\Phi(A) = A \setminus \{p\}$ can't be a reflection, since 
$$
\Phi(A\setminus \{p\}) = \Phi(\Phi(A)) = (\Phi \circ \Phi)(A) = A
$$
But
$$
\Phi(A \setminus \{p\}) \subset \Phi(A) \subsetneq A
$$
which means that we're down to rotations.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott actually, should we assume that the isometry on $A$ extends to an isometry over $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Don’t forget that rotations, reflections, and translations can be composed; there are examples in which reflections are involved, though possibly not essentially. And yes, the isometry must extend to $\Bbb R^2$. If $A$ is not collinear, this follows from the fact that a point is uniquely determined by the ordered triple of its distances from three fixed, non-collinear points. If $A$ is collinear, a similar argument using only two points extends it to the line containing $A$, and that isometry easily extends to the plane.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott any composition of transpostions, rotations, and reflections in $\Bbb R^2$ can be expressed either as a rotation about some point or a reflection a reflection across some line (not necessarily through the origin).  It's a quick exercise to see that this is the case using [linear transformations over homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix) to represent an affine transformation. Nice argument for the extension, that definitely works for me.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: You can’t express a simple translation that way: you need two reflections.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott hmmm, I misremembered then.  Certainly, however, every isometry can be expressed as a rotation followed by a translation, or as a reflection followed by a translation.

Comment: Can two isometries in two dimensions generate a free group? If so, let $G=\langle f,g\rangle$ be such a group and $x$ be a point with trivial stabilizer in $G$ (which can be seen to exist since $G$ is countable and all non-identity elements fix at most a set of measure $0$). Let $G'$ be the subset of $G$ of elements which, when written as products of $f$ and $g$ with no cancellation, do not end with $f^{-1}f^{-1}$ or $g^{-1}g^{-1}$. I think then $A\setminus\{f^{-1}(x)\}$ and $A\setminus \{g^{-1}(x)\}$ are isometric to $A$. (This might be wrong; I'm a little confused)

Comment: The claim "if $A$ \ $\left\{q \right\}$ is isometric to $A$ \ $\left\{p \right\}$, then $p=q$" is false in general: take $A= S^1$, $p=(0,1)$, $q=(0,-1)$. Then  $A$ \ $\left\{q \right\}$ is isometric to $A$ \ $\left\{p \right\}$ via the canonical rotation with matrix representation $-I$ but obviously $p \neq q$. So in a putative proof by contradiction of this proposition, we should probably avoid considering the induced isometry  $A$ \ $\left\{q \right\}$ $\rightarrow$ $A$ \ $\left\{p \right\}$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: $Isom(R^2)$ contains no nonabelian free subgroups. But this argument does show that the claim fails for subsets of $R^3$.

Comment: Question is answered here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255448/a-question-about-subsets-of-plane

Comment: @BenG. is there not a purely analytic solution? I would be disappointed if this is true (and disgusted by Sally)

Comment: @MoisheCohen Really? With uncountably many possible rotation anlges (around two different points) and only countably many possible relations, that seems to suggest that some relations hold "generically". And that sounds unexpected to me.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes, this is really true. The orientation-preserving subgroup of $Isom(E^2)$ is metabelian (the commutator subgroup is the group of translations, the abelianization is isomorphic to $S^1$) and hence, contains no nonabelian free subgroups.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: One more thing: $Isom(E^2)$ does contain a nonabelian free subsemigroup.

Comment: There is bounty

Comment: @GuyFsone: Why did you assign a bounty here, at MSE? It looks like an invitation to post incorrect solutions. The problem was solved by YCor in his answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255448/a-question-about-subsets-of-plane.

Comment: @MoisheCohen 
 
I was not aware of that, solution OOOps It is too late

Comment: I will post a cw answer to the question just with a link to MO answer (once this bounty expires) to discourage further pointless bounties.

Comment: It's been a long, long time since I asked this, but I didn't mind the extra bounty because some part of me still believes there should be an elementary (and analytic) proof. As I've said many times, this was literally in the third chapter of an introductory analysis textbook.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a formal answer to question. But just to let future readers and the OP know that a brilliant and detailed  solution to this problem can be found [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/255478) in mathobverflow.
This was prosed by @Ycor.

Answer (score 3):

This is an elementary proof in the case that neither isometry is a rotation. Suppose there to be isometries $P$ mapping $A$ to $A \setminus \{p\}$ and  $Q$ mapping $A$ to $A \setminus \{q\}, p≠q$. $P$ and  $Q$ cannot be self-inverse and so are either translations, glide reflections or rotations. Unless one or both of the isometries are rotations we therefore know that $P^2$ and $Q^2$ are both translations.

If  $P^2$ and $Q^2$ are not parallel translations, the effect on a point of successively performing $Q^2$ $n$ times, then $P^{-2}$ $ n$ times, then $Q^{-2}$ $ n$ times and finally $P^2 $$n$ times is to make the point traverse $4n$ points of a parallelogram. Furthermore, by increasing the value of $n$, we can make the second and third edges of this parallelogram as far from the points  $p,P(p),q$ and $ Q(q)$  as we wish. Starting from $P(p) ∈A$ we can therefore assume that all of the $4n$ points are  also in $A$. In particular,$$P^{-1} (p)= P^{2(n-1)}  Q^{-2n} P^{-2n} Q^{2n} P(p)∈A,$$ a contradiction.

If $P^2$ and $Q^2$ are parallel translations then first suppose 
$P$ and $ Q $ are glide reflections with parallel but not equal axes. Then $ PQ $ can be used in place of $ Q^2$ in the above case. Otherwise, $P$ and  $Q$ commute and then $Q^{-1} (p)∈A$ since $p≠q$. Therefore $P^{-1} Q^{-1} (p)∈A$ since $Q^{-1} (p)≠p$. Then $P^{-1} (p)=QP^{-1} Q^{-1}(p)∈A$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why should an isometry of A with A-p necessarily extend to an isometry of R^2? (Which is what I presume you are using in order to classify isometries into translations, rotations, etc.)

Comment: I was assuming from the outset that we were dealing with isometries of the Euclidean plane.

Comment: $A$ is a metric space in its own right, and the notion of "isometry of $A$" makes no reference to its living in $\mathbb R^2$...

Comment: The question does not use the phrase  "isometry of A" . I chose to use isometries of the Euclidean plane  for  "an elementary proof" in some cases.